# Keep Unity program working in background after device goes to sleep?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity project that uses the device camera for AR purposes (I'm using AR Foundation). I currently have it set so that the device won't go to sleep (because I want it to operate for long-periods without user-interaction). Specifically, Screen.sleepTImeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep. If I didn't have this, then the device would go to sleep, and the program would stop functioning. Does anyone know if there is a way to keep the program working in the background after the device goes to sleep...similar to how music apps keep playing music? I've come up empty handed after a few hours of searching for a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Some people aren't finding this in more recent versions of Unity. But it's still there: In Player settings, under the section "Resolution and Presentation", you find "Resolution" and below that, there's "Run In Background".

This is only available for Web players and standalones (Anything Except IOS And Android Pretty Much), though (you won't find it when you have the iOS, Android or Flash tab selected.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  Unfortunately, the two platforms I'm interested in running this project on are iOS and Android.  I should have included that information in my first post...apologies.    Given that, you have any other approaches that might work?  Thanks so much for the response!